# Remove an element from list at a given position

Tags: ocaml

what is wrong with my syntax?
findpos is used for finding position of an element

```
let delete x l =
    let pos = findpos x l in
    let rec remove_at pos l = function
    [] -> []
    | h :: t ->
        if pos = 1 then n t else h :: remove_at pos t
;;
```

Comment: To get more helpful answers, you should show the error message  for the syntax error you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Every `let` in OCaml (except at the top level of a module) requires a matching `in`. Your first `let` is at the top level of a module. Your second `let` has a matching `in`. Your third `let` doesn't have an `in`. I suspect that's the error you're asking about.